# Заменить onClick() на Onkeyup

Tags: javascript

Как изменить вывод результата скрипта по onkeyup в question? Тобишь без кнопки - автоматически, после ввода текста выводить результат

```js
const TEXTElement = document.getElementById('text');

function onClick() {
  const TEXT = TEXTElement.value;
  const QUESTIONS = TEXT.match(/вопрос:.*?(?=<br>)/gi);
  const QUESTIONS_HTML = QUESTIONS.join("<br>");
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = QUESTIONS_HTML;
  }
```

```html
<textarea id=text> </textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<div id="question"></div>
```

Comment: Просто добавить атрибут onkeyup для textarea?

Comment: почему-то не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const TEXTElement = document.getElementById('text');

// Текст для проверки:
// Transfer: Вопрос: почему сегодня такая плохая погода<br><br> Ответ: Мы сами не знаем<br>Вопрос: хорошо спасибо<br><br>

// Так же можно слушать событие 'input', так как ввод с клавиатуры
// не единственный способ введения данных в форму
TEXTElement.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyup);

function onKeyup() {
  const TEXT = TEXTElement.value;
  const QUESTIONS = TEXT.match(/вопрос:.*?(?=<br>)/gi);
  // Если не делать проверку на null выполнение функции может завершится с ошибкой
  if (QUESTIONS != null) {
    const QUESTIONS_HTML = QUESTIONS.join("<br>");
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = QUESTIONS_HTML;
  }
  // опционально можно добавить else блок, который будет стирать данные
  // если нет совпадений с регулярным выражением
  // else document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = ''
}
```

```html
<textarea id=text> </textarea>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
<div id="question"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам пример:

```js
function showResult(event) {
  //проверка функции
  document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = event.value;
  //...... код функции ....
}
```

```html
<textarea id=text onKeyUp="showResult(this)"></textarea>
<div id="question"></div>
```